# How to get rid of the undefined message on Chrome?

Tags: javascript

How to get rid of the undefined message after `console.log()` a variable

```js
var example = 5;
console.log(example);
```

output: 5
undefined

Comment: Why does it bother you that you get an extra message in the *developer console*?

Comment: don't type `console.log(example);` in the console, but simply `example`

Comment: Right, It basically happens when nothing is returned from your execution. Just it logs the output of statements statements.

Comment: @Cid why you correct my edit? He wrong to write console, and if was that the problem? Because that's only possible problem of that simple code.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini if that would have been the problem, the error message would have been really different

Answer (score 0):

You can't:

> The reason the debug console outputs undefined after a function, is because you're running the function (`example()`) and then in the function body, there is no return statement so by default, the return statement will return `undefined`.

*[More about `return` statements at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)*

The reason it does, is: say you have a function called example

```js
function example() {
  // Code here
}
```

Using the return statement inside the function, will return something:

```js
function example() {
  // Code here
  return "Some string";
}
```

By default (with no return statement) there will be an `undefined` return statement.

```js
function example() {
  // Code here
}

example(); // undefined
```

```js
function example() {
  // Code here
  return true;
}

example(); // true
```

Also, it does not happen only on Chrome. It happens on all modern and old browsers with JavaScript enabled.